# C# Write as Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am passing an argument to my method wherein the datatype of this is string, but this string is a binary type "UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDfz5sukgEAAJQGAAATANwBW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZ" for example, then this parameter will then be written into an excel format.  The problem is, the file can be created but is corrupted due to invalid format.  The input parameter comes from an excel file but is read as binary.

My sample code is:

```
public void writeFile(String fileContent)
{       
    // Write the string to a file.
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("c:\\test2.xlsx");
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file);

    bw.Write(fileContent);

    bw.Close();
    file.Close();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you read in a *.xlsx-File as a String and trying to write it back (without altering the string) to a *.xlsx-File?

Comment: Yes, because the reason why I'm doing this is because I wanted to transfer a file from a web service client into a web service host.  So, on the client side, it reads the binary Content of the excel, then on the web service host side, it reads the binary Content and writes it into an excel.  I am not allowed to use FTP so I'm using the web service implementation instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary data can not be send or use them as text/string as is, and the reason is that that there are binary numbers that you can not represent them with text characters - at the same time some binary numbers have different meaning in a string.

What you can do is to convert it to string using one of

- MIME (with Base64)
- UUEncode
- XXEncode

and then convert it back to binary

The asp.net have all ready the `Convert.ToBase64String` and `Convert.FromBase64String` to make the convert.

The convert functions from asp.net:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx

a custom convert example
 http://www.csharp411.com/convert-binary-to-base64-string/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, I did get managed to fix the issue by using     Convert.FromBase64String(fileContent) then use     File.WriteAllBytes.

Answer (score 0):

if bytes are coming as string use code as follows:

```
    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(bytesAsString);
                                File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, base64EncodedBytes);
```

Hope this helps.